# Android Firebase query with range (Above, Mid, Bottom)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just start using Firebase in Android and I wrote query like this.

```
messageSearchQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Message")
    .child(conversationID).limitToLast(INITIAL_MESSAGE_COUNT)
    .orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(participant.joiningDate).endAt(endAt);
```

I can only give `limitToFirst`, `limitToLast`, `startAt`, `endAt`. (I think there is no center)

I need to give timestamp (e.g 10 am sharp) and i wanna query 10 message before 10 am and 10 message after 10 am. (but i don't know when it start, when it end).

Edit

What I want to do is something like this.

```
messageSearchQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Message").
                    child(conversationID).
                    orderByChild("timestamp").equalTo(endAt).limitToFirst(INITIAL_MESSAGE_COUNT).limitToLast(INITIAL_MESSAGE_COUNT);
```

But if I do, it crash like this.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't call limitToLast on query with previously set limit!

How shall I do?

My data in firebase is something like this.

[image]

Comment: My quick answer is below. If that doesn't work for you, show a bit more of what you're trying to do. E.g. it would be really helpful to see your JSON (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). It would also help if you replace all the variables that we can't see with hardcoded values that reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have put my sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a range by combining `startAt` and `endAt`, both of which operate on the child you order on. For example if you want messages between 10am and 10pm on a certain date, you'd do:

```
long timestampOf10am = ...;
long timestampOf10pm = ...;
messageSearchQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Message")
  .child(conversationID)
  .orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(timestampOf10am).endAt(timestampOf10pm)
  .limitToLast(INITIAL_MESSAGE_COUNT);
```

**Update**: If you need 10 items before 10am and 10 items after 10am, you'll need to fire two queries and merge the results client-side.

```
long timestampOf10am = ...;
beforeMessageSearchQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Message")
  .child(conversationID)
  .orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(timestampOf10am)
  .limitToFirst(INITIAL_MESSAGE_COUNT);
afterMessageSearchQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Message")
  .child(conversationID)
  .orderByChild("timestamp").endAt(timestampOf10am)
  .limitToLast(INITIAL_MESSAGE_COUNT);
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem is I don't know  timestamp for startAt, endAt. I only know my 1 timestamp (10 am sharp) and I need to query 10 message before 10 am and 10 message after 10 am. How shall I do?

Comment: Ah, that requires two queries: one with `startAt().limitToFirst()` and one with `endAt().limitToLast()`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to combine those 2 query? If not, I gonna try with two queries.

Comment: No, there is no way to combine them. You'll need two queries.